# python: function is not calling

Tags: python-2.7

Code is working till yesterday. Suddenly one of the function is not getting called.

All scripts are in the same folder, calling script and called script.

I have put couple of print statements in _fbbqinsert and tried running the _fbbqinsert alone and it is working fine.

The function is not calling properly.

[image]

**Script name : fbutils**

```
import json
import os, sys
import pandas as pd
import errno
import time
import glob
import datetime
import requests
import fbbqfuns

def _callXML():
  try:
    print "Calling fbbqinsert"
    fbbqfuns._fbbqinsert(report_run_id,cfg,file_name,0)

  except:
    exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
```

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `*.pyc` files.

And yeah, it would be nice to see stack trace.